# How I can read several files

Tags: command-line, command

How can I read several files and extract only certain lines and write them in their own appropriate file
Example:

```
file1.txt - file1_output;
file2.txt - file2_output;
file3.txt - file3_output;
file4.txt - file4_output;
file5.txt - file5_output;
```

```bsh
more *.log | cat 
cat *.log | tee file1.txt file2.txt
```

```
File1:
    at com.lhs.ccb.sfw.application.ServiceObjectImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.lhs.cil.core.AggregatedServiceObjectImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.lhs.ccb.sfw.application.ServiceObjectImpl.validateI(Unknown Source)
    at com.lhs.ccb.soi.ServiceObjectIPOA._invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1700)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1558)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:940)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:198)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:519)

РЯа. 19, 2021 4:14:16 PM com.lhs.ccb.sfw.application.ServiceObjectImpl executeLocaleI
SEVERE: ServiceObjectI.executeLocaleI CONTRACT.WRITE

File2:
Error code: CommonDomain.InvalidStateTransition
    at com.lhs.CommonDomain.bscs_core.ae.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.lhs.Contract.bscs_core.services.ContractWrite.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.lhs.cil.core.AggregatedServiceObjectImpl.executeLocaleI(Unknown Source)
    at com.lhs.ccb.soi.ServiceObjectIPOA._invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:198)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:519)

РЯа. 19, 2021 4:14:16 PM com.lhs.FrameworkExtension.bscs_core.d getErrorMessage
WARNING: no localized text available for:
ErrorCode : InvalidStateTransition
BundleName: CommonDomain_ErrorDictionary
Locale    : en_US
Reason    : XMlResourceException: ResourceBundleManager: Can not find resource bundle 'CommonDomain_ErrorDictionary'
РЯа. 19, 2021 4:14:16 PM com.lhs.FrameworkExtension.bscs_core.d getErrorMessage
WARNING: no localized text available for:
ErrorCode : InvalidStateTransition
BundleName: CommonDomain_ErrorDictionary
Locale    : en_US
Reason    : XMlResourceException: ResourceBundleManager: Can not find resource bundle 'CommonDomain_ErrorDictionary'
РЯа. 19, 2021 4:15:42 PM com.lhs.ccb.sfw.application.ServiceObjectImpl executeLocaleI
SEVERE: ServiceObjectI.executeLocaleI CONTRACT.WRITE

File3:
Error code: CommonDomain.InvalidStateTransition
    at com.lhs.CommonDomain.bscs_core.ae.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.lhs.Contract.bscs_core.services.ContractWrite.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.lhs.Contract.bscs_core.services.ContractWrite.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.lhs.cil.core.LocalCommandAdapter.localExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.lhs.cil.core.AggregatedServiceObjectImplProxy.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1558)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:519)

РЯа. 19, 2021 4:15:42 PM com.lhs.FrameworkExtension.bscs_core.d getErrorMessage
WARNING: no localized text available for:
ErrorCode : InvalidStateTransition
BundleName: CommonDomain_ErrorDictionary
Locale    : en_US
Reason    : XMlResourceException: ResourceBundleManager: Can not find resource bundle 'CommonDomain_ErrorDictionary'
РЯа. 19, 2021 4:15:42 PM com.lhs.FrameworkExtension.bscs_core.d getErrorMessage
WARNING: no localized text available for:
ErrorCode : InvalidStateTransition
BundleName: CommonDomain_ErrorDictionary
Locale    : en_US
Reason    : XMlResourceException: ResourceBundleManager: Can not find resource bundle 'CommonDomain_ErrorDictionary'
РЯа. 19, 2021 4:17:19 PM com.lhs.ccb.sfw.application.ServiceObjectImpl executeLocaleI
SEVERE: ServiceObjectI.executeLocaleI CONTRACT.WRITE

OUTPUT:
FILE1_OUTPUT: SEVERE line... from File1
FILE2_OUTPUT: SEVERE line... from File2
FILE3_OUTPUT: SEVERE line... from File3
```

***SEVERE line is always on a different position

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do or what your code example is showing. Do you want to run `grep` to extract lines matching particular patterns? Could you give examples showing short files containing lines that you want to extract and lines that you don't want to extract, and where you want to write these lines?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `awk` as following:

```
awk 'FNR==1{ close(ofname); ofname="output_"FILENAME } 
  /^SEVERE/{ print >ofname }' infile*
```